# Playing 3D Animation in iPhone App (Possibly using a looping video)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, video, animation, 3d

Is there a relatively easy was to include a 3D animation into an iPhone app? We have the animations already made up for another project and our client has asked if they can be placed inside an iPhone app. We could perhaps include a low-res looping video of the animation (it's just a 3D component rotating on a single axis), or would it be better to look into getting the 3D animation directly onto a view?

Cheers,
Dan

Comment: I was looking for a mesh viewer today, and I can only find SDK's. For a single rotation axis, I think quicktime has "special" support for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either split it up into a set of frames and use the UIView animationImages property like so:

http://appsamuck.com/day2.html

Or assuming its already an OpenGL animation you could port the code to openGLES.

Here are good tutorials for openGL ES:

http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/05/opengl-es-from-ground-up-table-of.html